# Pandas: concat function removes prior sorting of dataframes

Tags: python, pandas

Consider two dataframes called "socio_demo" ([198 rows x 15 columns]) and UPDRS_sorted([198 rows x 70 columns]).
Let's do:

```
socio_demo_sorted = socio_demo.sort_values(['NUMERO_CENTRE_1','NUMERO_INCLUSION_1'])
UPDRS_sorted = UPDRS.sort_values(['NUMERO_CENTRE_2','NUMERO_INCLUSION_2'])
```

UPDRS_sorted['NUMERO_CENTRE_2'] gives

```
Out[22]: 
3     1
9     1
13    1
18    1
24    1
     ..
6     6
16    6
20    6
25    6
34    6
Name: NUMERO_CENTRE_2, Length: 198, dtype: int64
```

Now let's concatenate the two sorted datasets:

```
frames = [socio_demo_sorted,UPDRS_sorted]
full_data = pd.concat(frames,axis = 1)
```

which gives the expected [198 rows x 85 columns] shape.
However, doing

```
full_data['NUMERO_CENTRE_2']
```

returns the original (non-sorted) UPDRS data:

```
0      3
1      4
2      2
3      1
4      5
      ..
193    1
194    1
195    1
196    1
197    1
Name: NUMERO_CENTRE_2, Length: 198, dtype: int64
```

I don't understand why the effect of the ".sort_values" function is lost here.

Answer (score 2):

The row indexes of the original unsorted dataframes were retained after sorting (although they were shuffled after sorting).  After you concat the 2 sorted dataframes, the concatenated dataframe was re-arranged based on these original indexes.  Hence, returned to the unsorted orders.

You can solve this either by resetting index with `.reset_index(drop=True)` of the sorted dataframes or directly by using parameter `ignore_index=True` during the sort step:

Use either:

```
socio_demo_sorted = socio_demo.sort_values(['NUMERO_CENTRE_1','NUMERO_INCLUSION_1']).reset_index(drop=True)
UPDRS_sorted = UPDRS.sort_values(['NUMERO_CENTRE_2','NUMERO_INCLUSION_2']).reset_index(drop=True)
```

or by:

```
socio_demo_sorted = socio_demo.sort_values(['NUMERO_CENTRE_1','NUMERO_INCLUSION_1'], ignore_index=True)
UPDRS_sorted = UPDRS.sort_values(['NUMERO_CENTRE_2','NUMERO_INCLUSION_2'], ignore_index=True)
```

Then, concat as per your codes:

```
frames = [socio_demo_sorted,UPDRS_sorted]
full_data = pd.concat(frames,axis = 1)
```

Comment: ++ but the second one doesn't seem to work, does it? I think in some cases it already comes in e.g., 0...N-1 order but I might be missing things. Perhaps we can `ignore_index` in `sort_values` but equivalent is the `reset_index` solution of yours i guess.

Comment: @MustafaAydın  Thanks for pointing out.  Yes, since the concat is on axis=1, ignore_index doesn't work on it.   Should use the first solution only.

Answer (score 1):

In your case when `concat` do `ignore_index`

```
out = pd.concat(frames,ignore_index=True)
```